# Ensure latest versions of files on Amazon Cloudfront always show in browsers?

Tags: cdn, amazon-cloudfront

I'd like to run my web site entirely off S3 + Cloudfront. Each page will be a .html file which may be updated/overwritten once or twice daily with new content. I've chosen this architecture to reduce load time.

My site consists of around 100 .html files. I have a cronjob which updates maybe 15 - 20 files daily, as new data is added to my database. The home page (index.html) may change even more often.

Is it possible to always ensure browsers always receive the latest versions of files (rather than from browser cache) for my site while retaining the same URLs (e.g., /index.html, /category/product-name.html) if there are updates?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out you can tell Cloudfront to honor its origin headers. So let's say you upload files to an S3 bucket which acts as Cloudfront's origin. You can set some headers, as follows

```
Cache-Control:no-cache no-store max-age=0 must-revalidate
Expires:0
```

on upload, and Cloudfront will honor these.

I uploaded a test.html file to S3, viewed it on my Cloudfront domain, and then once I uploaded a new version to S3, the new version was instantly available on Cloudfront. And Cloudfront sends the above mentioned headers to the browser, and so the browser obeys the caching rules.

However, it seems as though the average latency for accessing the file on Cloudfront may have increased with these headers in place. Originally, latency averaged around 90ms - 100ms, whereas with the headers, it's around 110ms. Not that big of a deal considering the benefits of uptime, hosting fees, and that 110ms is still pretty darn fast.

Comment: That is not a very good approach, as it means that effectively you don't use the benefits of your cdn - almost every hit also hits the origin server. With this small number of daily updates I'd try to use CloudFront API to invalidate the touched htmls - you have 1000 free monthly invalidations, so it shouldn't be a problem for you.

Comment: @danbars I invalidated my html, and it broke my whole site. Also, for invalidating you have to pay per file.

Comment: @Chad Johnson where should these headers be entered?

Comment: Not sure — it’s been too long, and I’ve unfortunately forgotten :( I also wonder if headers alone are enough or if both headers and invalidation should be used, together. Or maybe invalidation is enough.